# Object not found [XAMPP]

Tags: apache, xampp, php

Загружаю http://localhost/test1.ru  (C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.ru)
мне выдает

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on
> this server. If you entered the URL
> manually please check your spelling
> and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error,
> please contact the webmaster. Error
> 404

В папке test1.ru в файле htaccess прописано

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

**vhosts**

```
> <VirtualHost *:80>   ServerAdmin
> postmaster@blog   DocumentRoot
> "C:/xampp/htdocs/test1.ru"
>     ServerName test1.ru    ServerAlias www.test1.ru   ErrorLog
> "logs/test1.ru-error.log"    CustomLog
> "logs/test1.ru-access.log" combined
> </VirtualHost>
```

**httpd.conf**
**DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"**

Comment: что пишет апач в логи?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2013:06:32:01 +0300] "GET /test1.ru HTTP/1.1" 404 1042 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"  -файл blog-access

Comment: не может найти такую страницу http://localhost/test1.ru, смотри httpd-vhosts, что там...? DocumentRoot куда настроен?

Comment: windows,обновил вопрос.

Comment: с `command line` запустите `httpd`.